# How to import excel to Redmine

Tags: ruby, redmine

Today I have a task from my boss that I have to study redmine and tell him if we can import issues excel file to redmine.
I don't know anything about redmine. Can we import issues excel file to redmine? And if we can, what I should start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here: https://github.com/leovitch/redmine_importer/wiki

You can use Excel to export a CSV file, then use the Redmine importer to import the items.

This presumes that your Excel items are reasonably typical, and do not have embedded calculations, images, special fonts, etc.

Comment: It seems like the original plugin is not maintained any more. But there currently are thee maintained forks: https://github.com/gc-olivierho/redmine_importer, https://github.com/agileware-jp/redmine_importer and https://github.com/zh/redmine_importer

Answer (score 3):

Since 3.2.0 Redmine has support for importing issues. I just started a minimal howto: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_import_issues

Answer (score 0):

Start here: https://github.com/conveniencable/redmine_excel_connector

After install this redmien plugin and Excel VSTO plugin, you can just load & save issues in excel.